# How to create divisions in Javascript that are mathematically correct and acceptable

Tags: javascript, html, math, rounding, division

The code does not create allways mathematically correct divisions, for exp. it creats divisions like 2/0 etc. and it also does not accept for "1/3" rounded answers like "0.33" or "0.33333". What do I need to change in the code? 
Thanks for your help and time.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", question);

var mulDiv = document.getElementById("mulDiv");

function question()
{
var startButton = document.getElementById("button1");
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
var decider = Math.random();
    
button1.textContent = "New Question";
number1.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
number2.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
    

mulDiv.textContent = "/"  

};

document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", answer);


function answer()
{
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").textContent, 10);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").textContent, 10);
var answer = parseInt(document.getElementById("userAnswer").value, 10);
var feedBack = document.getElementById("feedBack");
    
     
if (mulDiv.textContent == "/"){
if(answer == num1 / num2) {
feedBack.textContent = "right";

} else {
feedBack.textContent = "wrong";
}
}
       
};
```

```html
<button id = "button1">
Start
</button>

<p>
<label id = "number1"> </label>
<label id = "mulDiv"> </label>
<label id = "number2"> </label>
 = <input id = "userAnswer" type=text>
<button id = "button2">Answer</button>
</p>

<p id = "feedBack"> </p>
```

Comment: Binary floating-point math can do all sorts of unexpected things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line of code:

```
number2.textContent = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
```

generates random numbers from 0 to 4, because `Math.random()` returns a number from 0 to 1(not including 1). You should do:

```
number2.textContent = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
```

That way the minimum will be 1 and the maximum will be 5.